# How to concatenate strings and integer into a variable

Tags: android, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

It is a real silly questions but I can't get it to work. I've used the search option, but couldn't not find my answer for android.

What I would like to do it the following:

In res/strings.xml i've got several strings

```
<string name="good0">blablabla</string>
<string name="good1">balablabla2</string>
etc
```

I want to show those strings randomly in a those when something happens:

```
Toast.makeText(this,R.string.good+(Math.random()*10), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But this doesn't work.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why don't you use StringArray instead? There's no way to do that!

Comment: I will go for the StringArray, I think it is a better solution than using a case. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `String Array`.

In `strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="messages">
        <item>blablabla</item>
        <item>blablabla</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then, in code you will have something like:

```
String[] messages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.messages);
Random r = new Random();
String message = messages[r.nextInt(messages.length)];
Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.

You will have to use a `switch` block.

```
String myString;

switch(Math.random() * 10) {
   case 0:
       myString = getString(R.string.good1);
       break;
}

Toast.makeText(this, myString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Wasn't expecting that it wasn't possible. But thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: R.string.good1 will just put an int in to the String.  This won't work without using the appropriate `getString()` call.

Comment: I don't think it's an good idea, espcially when there're a lot of Strings.

Answer (score 2):

`R.string.good` is an `int` because it refers to a Resource.  This int IDENTIFIES a string in an XML file.  Android provides a `getString()` for its resource identifiers.

[Android Docs on String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

You'll have to get the String out of the resource file this way, then concatenate as normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple string values or integer values and you to store it in a single string then String Builder is the best for this
 type of operation, For Example you have a string array and you want to
 store in a single string and then display this string then use this
 method. it will work hundred percent and it is too much suitable for
 this type of problems.**

```
String my_str=null;
StringBuilder bldr=new StringBuilder();
for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
  bldr.append(phonearray[j]).append(",");
my_str=bldr.toString();
```

here in this case i am assigning phone array to a single string and
 then i will display it  etc...